# Cannot connect to torproject.org in chrome (win7)

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I was trying to access the Tor project's official website through Chrome in Windows 7, but it didn't let me continue. Instead, Chrome told me that it cannot connect to the real www.torproject.org and I might share info with an attacker if I visit it (I'm attaching images of the warning message). Meanwhile, Firefox doesn't find any trouble in connecting to the site.

I need help in understanding whats happening here. Is it really an attacker trying to get into my system or a problem with chrome..?

BTW, here's a discussion I found on the same topic https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2012-January/022635.html. Its been dated back to '12 but nothing helpful (for me at least!) have happened there.
Also, we have a Sophos web protection installed in the college server through which I'm using internet.

[image: msg 1]

[image: msg 2]

Comment: I think the first answer does not really address the problem. I do not suspect that this has to do with Tor.

Comment: Your question is not really about the Tor software. I'll migrate the question to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has been compromised by the US security apparatus. Recommend you remove Chrome from your device and use Firefox... Search for 'chrome security issues' any search engine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Sophos is hijacking your connection. They offer you a SSL certificate which is not the original one from https://www.torproject.org/, but one made by Sophos. This way they are able to look inside your encrypted connection (also known as man-in-the-middle-attack).

This is not Tor's fault. Obviously your college breaks some (or all?) encrypted connections to look inside. There might be different reasons why your Firefox doesn't show this warning. Maybe it is administered by your college and they advised Firefox to trust every certificate issued by the Sophos software. Or you could also have accidentally accepted the certificate earlier.